# How to update charts from parent in vue3 with vue-chartjs 5.2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to vue and to be honest I don't understand how I can update a graph from its paren. With the vue-dev-tools I see that the data got updated, but doesn't trigger a graph update.
I find a lot of out-dated information for vue2 and older vue-chartjs api calls + the documentation for the new api for vue-chartjs, which doesn't help me. The vue-chartjs says that there are data watchers. So I assume, when I change the data, the graph updates. But something I'm missing here.

**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/v8rdgz

I'm using vue3 with

```
vue-chartjs@5.2.0
chart.js@4.3.0
```

I fiddled around with props, computed, refs but I didn't achieve my goal.
Here my minimal example. When the Update Graph Button is pressed. There should appear another line., another line should appear.

```
// LineChart.vue
<template>
  <Line :data="data" :options="options" />
</template>

<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export default {
  components: { Line },
  props: ["data", "options"],
};
</script>
```

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="updateGraph">Update Graph</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <LineChart :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from "./components/LineChart.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40],
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    LineChart,
  },

  methods: {
    updateGraph() {
      this.chartData.datasets.push({
        label: "Data Two",
        backgroundColor: "#f87979",
        data: [50, 59, 50, 50, 59, 50, 50],
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!!!
Best regards

Comment: Consider reproducing on codesandbox or similar. The [mcve] needs to be *runnable*.

Comment: Thank you!
Created a codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/v8rdgz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the update you're making is too deep. You need to replace `chartData` with an updated version of itself, instead of simply updating its `datasets`. `chart.js` does support mutating the `datasets` array, but Vue does not watch data updates deeply. So unless you replace `this.chartData`, Vue won't update `Line.vue`, used internally by `LineChart.vue`.

```
    updateGraph() {
      this.chartData = {
        ...this.chartData,
        datasets: [
          ...this.chartData.datasets, {
            label: "Data Two",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: [50, 59, 50, 50, 59, 50, 50],
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-leftpad-s72lm7?file=/src/App.vue).

---

Alternatively, you can tell Vue when the component needs to be re-rendered, by using `:key="chartData.datasets.length"` on your `<LineChart />` component. However, this method re-renders the chart from scratch, so you'll get the initial data animations, not the ones from old data state to new data state.

I recommend the first method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both solutions works perfectly fine!

I prefer the second one, because then there is no copying of data involved through creating a new object. I can imagine, when the datasets become bigger, that this can become a performance problem.
Also the code looks cleaner :). The animation is anoying, maybe I find a way to switch it off.

Comment: to disable the animation:
```
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: false,
      },
```